# Modbus rtu set serial mode Error

Tags: serial-port, modbus

I get an error when I use `modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode`. The error is thrown by `ioctl` saying `bad file descriptor`. After googling I found out that a dozen of people had problems with this, but sadly no solutions. If you have even the slightest clue what's going on, please at least set me in the right direction. I'm working in Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

```
#define MODBUS_RTU_RS232 0
#define MODBUS_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SEC 10
#define MODBUS_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_USEC 0

    //...
    std::string mode = "RTU";
    std::string port = "/dev/ttyO3";
    std::string commInterface = "RS232";
    int baudrate = 19200;    
    char parity = 'N';
    int dataBit = 8;
    int stopBit = 1; 
    int slaveAddress = 10;

    modbus_t *mb;

    //...
}

    //function calling the modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode
    //...
    if(mode = "RTU"){
       mb = modbus_new_rtu(port, baudrate, parity, dataBit, stopBit);
       if(mb == NULL)
       {
           return false;
       }
    }
    if(commInterface == "RS232"){
       if(modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(mb, MODBUS_RTU_RS232) < 0){
           std::cout << "modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode failed, errMsg: " 
                     << modbus_strerror(errno); //Here it prints "Bad File Descriptor"
           modbus_close(mb);
           modbus_free(mb);
           return false;
       }
    }

    struct timeval old_response_timeout;
    modbus_get_response_timeout(mb, &old_response_timeout);

    struct timeval response_timeout;
    response_timeout.tv_sec = MODBUS_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_SEC;
    response_timeout.tv_usec = MODBUS_RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_USEC;
    modbus_set_response_timeout(mb, &response_timeout);

    modbus_set_slave(mb, slaveAddress);

    int connectSlave = modbus_connect(mb);
    if (connectSlave < 0)
    {
        std::cout << "Slave error";
        modbus_close(mb);
        modbus_free(mb);
        return false;
    }    

//...
```

modbus-rtu.c file

```
int modbus_rtu_set_serial_mode(modbus_t *ctx, int mode)
{
    if (ctx->backend->backend_type == _MODBUS_BACKEND_TYPE_RTU) {
#if HAVE_DECL_TIOCSRS485
        modbus_rtu_t *ctx_rtu = ctx->backend_data;
        struct serial_rs485 rs485conf;
        memset(&rs485conf, 0x0, sizeof(struct serial_rs485));

        if (mode == MODBUS_RTU_RS485) {
            rs485conf.flags = SER_RS485_ENABLED;
            if (ioctl(ctx->s, TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            ctx_rtu->serial_mode |= MODBUS_RTU_RS485;
            return 0;
        } else if (mode == MODBUS_RTU_RS232) {

            if (ioctl(ctx->s, TIOCSRS485, &rs485conf) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }

            /*int status;
            status |= TIOCM_RTS;
            if (ioctl(ctx->s, TIOCMSET, &status) < 0) {
                return -1;
            }*/

            ctx_rtu->serial_mode = MODBUS_RTU_RS232;
            return 0;
        }
#else
        if (ctx->debug) {
            fprintf(stderr, "This function isn't supported on your platform\n");
        }
        errno = ENOTSUP;
        return -1;
#endif
    }

    /* Wrong backend and invalid mode specified */
    errno = EINVAL;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Hey! Just wondering if you fixed this issue, I am having same problem.

Comment: @Kam Not yet, our team has decided to ignore the issue at hand

Comment: I have the same issue under the Raspberry Pi... Any solutions? @TheGuyWithStreetCred how did you manage to ignore this and still get RS-485 half duplex communications?